# Rails: slug containing underscores not getting generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, slug

I an running a script on rails console to generate slug for profile brand names. This is my script:

```
class String
def to_slug
#strip the string
ret = self.strip.downcase

#blow away apostrophes
ret.gsub! /['`]/,""

# @ --> at, and & --> and
ret.gsub! /\s*@\s*/, " at "
ret.gsub! /\s*&\s*/, " and "

#replace all non alphanumeric, underscore or periods with hyphen
ret.gsub! /\s*[^A-Za-z0-9\.\-]\s*/, '-'

#convert double underscores to single
ret.gsub! /_+/,"_"

#strip off leading/trailing underscore
ret.gsub! /\A[_\.]+|[_\.]+\z/,""

ret
end
end

Profile.all.each do |profile|
if !profile.brand_name.nil? && profile.brand_name != profile.first_name
profile.slug = profile.brand_name.to_slug
profile.save
end
end
```

It is working perfectly for strings that do not contain underscores. But it doesnt generate slug for strings that contains underscore.

e.g. in brand name is "Kalpana's_Creations", slug of this brand name is "nil", which should be "kalpanas_creations"

This is what i see when rails console runs the script:

```
Profile Load (3.2ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` 
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Profile Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `profiles` WHERE (`profiles`.`brand_name` = BINARY 'Kalpana\'s_Creations' AND `profiles`.`id` != 6) LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I am not getting whats going wrong here. Can any body help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an `Profile Exists` error and after that ActiveRecord does a `ROLLBACK`. You didn't post your model but I guess that there is some sort of unique validation which triggers the rollback because there is already an entry with these values.

Comment: You are right. There was validation issue. Solved now. Thanks.